# React external script console log not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

As the questions states, I loaded an external script by putting this line in index.html

```
<script type="text/js"  src="../src/js/compress.js"></script>
```

And my compress.js is like this

```
import axios from "axios";
import Compressor from "compressorjs";

$(document).ready (function() {
  console.log("asass");
});
```

My console shows,

[image]

Am I missing anything so obvious? Why does't console log messages show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not correct way to add external script into your react code.

your componnent

```
// src/path/Compressor.js

...
export default YourCompressor;
```

another file

```
// src/App.js
import YourCompressor from "./path/Compressor.js";
...
```

it's enough only and do not need to add your file external.

don't forget using `import` has error in browsers and you have to use **bable** for using reactjs.

Comment: YourCompressor in your example is a component right?

Comment: Yes but in do not write implemention of `YourCompressor`.